# Как добавить атрибуты в SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml

Создаю обьект SimpleXMLElement так

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<yml_catalog date="' . date("Y-m-d H:i") . '"/>');
```

При этом получаю адекватные

```
<yml_catalog date="2018-09-04 17:20"></yml_catalog>
```

Далее формирую массив $data cложной структуры.

```
[
    'offser id="228"' =>[
        "url" => http://rnhubpo.com
        "price" => 30
        "currencyId" => UAH
        "categoryId" => 713
        "picture" => IMG
        "vendor" => brazzzers
        "stock_quantity" => 30
        "name" => Кто-то тут
        "description" => descriptions
        'param name="Артикул"' => 1488
    ]
]
```

В даных мне нужно также использовать атрибуты. Но как быть с закрывающимися тегами?

XML получаю методом

```
function bildXml(\SimpleXMLElement &$xml, $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $retXml = $xml->addChild($k);
                $this->bildXml($retXml , $v);
            } else
                $xml->addChild($k, $v);
        }
    }
```

Работает как часы за исключением атрибутов.

Получаю что-то типа

```
<offser id="228"></offser id="228">
```

Comment: Аттрибуты на узел надо ручками добавлять, через `addAttribute` - http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но как быть с массивом даных? Получается теряется все удобство в генерации даных.

Comment: Сформируйте по-другому, укажите что некоторые поля массива - аттрибуты.

Comment: Ок, если не найдётся более просторе решение, напишу метод который будет эксплоудить ключ и создавать верный xml на базе выше указанного метода

Comment: Если вы генерируете массив сами - генерируйте сразу __нужной__ структуры, не надо придумывать себе задач с эксплодами, парсингом строк регулярными выражениями и прочим. Зачем?

Comment: Да, только он на много-много больше и сложнее, как-то отдельно задать атрибуты в масиве довольно сложно, чтобы его потом так-же просто было генерировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добработал метод следующим образом

```
function bildXml(\SimpleXMLElement &$xml, $data)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $keyData = explode(" ",$k);
        $key = array_shift($keyData);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $retXml = $xml->addChild($key);
            $this->bildXml($retXml, $v);
        } else
           $retXml = $xml->addChild($key, $v);
        if(count($keyData) > 0){
            foreach($keyData as $d){
                $d = str_replace("\"","",$d);
                $attr = explode("=",$d);
                $retXml->addAttribute($attr[0],$attr[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Вызов**

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<yml_catalog/>');
$this->bildXml($xml, $data);
$xml = $xml->asXML();
```